# Android Studio: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo..ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android

I used Android Studio 1.2 to create a new project then run it, but it couldn't work.The errors is below:

```
com.example.android.lifecycle E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.android.lifecycle, PID: 8674
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.lifecycle/com.example.android.lifecycle.ActivityA}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.android.lifecycle.ActivityA" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.lifecycle-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2236)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Answer (score 0):

### I reinstall Android Studio and upgrade to 1.3.1, but the pre-created project also couldn't work.Through comparing the project and a new project, i find the solution:

1. All activities extends AppCompatActivity
2. Project's build.gradle should dependencies `gradle:1.3.0`
3. `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip`

I tried these differences, and found when i change the distributionUrl to 2.4 version ,all is well.

Comment: I think All activities doesn't have to extend AppCompatActivity.

Comment: @ChungPham yeah, you're right.In Android Studio 1.2, the activity extends ActionBarActivity.Thank you, i have edited my answer.